# $_Post problems

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is this notice referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065978/what-is-this-notice-referring-to)

can i get an answer in plain English please 
i am new at this .. the better it is explained the fewer times i will need to repost

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\espn.com\login.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\espn.com\login.php on line 17

1<?php
2
3//Database Information
4
5 $dbhost = "localhost";
6 $dbname = "users";
7 $dbuser = "root";
8 $dbpass = "*****";
9
10 //Connect to database
11
12 mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
13 mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
14
15 session_start();
****16 $username = $_POST['username'];
17 $password = md5($_POST['password']);****
18
19 $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="%s" AND password="%s"',
20    ($username), ($password));
21
22 $result = mysql_query($query);
23
if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
$error = "Bad Login";
    include "login.html";

} else {
    $_SESSION['username'] = "$username" ;
    include "memberspage.php";
}
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of your own questions ( [what is this notice referring to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065978/what-is-this-notice-referring-to) ), if you have new or additional information relevant to the same question, edit your original question and add the new/additional information.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to get an answer, but asking duplicate questions is not going to help you out here, instead try editing this question as to clarify your intentions and exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. The form that is submitted does not have any name tag.
Please fix your html part as follow:

```
<input **name="username"**/>
```

So that you can easily use $_POST['username'] to recover the value from the form.
Actually every time you see "undefined index" it means that a key of an array is missing.
It's like:

```
$a = array('zero', 'one', 'two');
```

and you calling:

```
$a[3];
```

In this case $_POST is a global array which is missing the key 'username' and 'password'.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a page, the data (*user input / form dat*a) is sent as an array which you can access via `$_POST`.

Now, when you access `$_POST[somename]`, the PHP engine tries to retrieve the value for the key "somename" in the array `$_POST`.

In your program (specifically lines 16 & 17), the key for the array does not exist.

So, it is better you do a check like this:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:null;
```